# Tikz graphic good in my tex book, bad in the beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am working on a beamer presententaion about complex number based in text that I have been writting. I am copying and paste my text to beamer. but in this part the output file has an ugly difference. First I will show you my text

[image]
And here it is the result if I pate this code in my beamer

[image]
Here it is the code used if anyone of you can help me, Thanks in advance.

````
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5, xmax=4, ymin=-.5, ymax=2.5] 
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}] 
\tkzDefPoint(3,2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](z)
\tkzDrawSegments(C,A C,B)
\tkzLabelSegment[above=0.1](C,A){$|z|$}
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=gray!30,size=1cm](B,C,A)
\tkzPointShowCoord[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$](A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.5](A,C,B){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document} ```
````

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Please don't post screen shots of code (they are hard to read and we cannot cut and paste from them), and please expand the code that you have posted to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE  should be a *minimal* piece of code that compiles and demonstrates your problem. The code you have posted does not have a `\documentclass` command and it does not seem to use beamer. This said, I suspect thath you just need `\begin{frame}[fragile]...\end{frame}`.

Comment: @Andrew `\documentclass` was not displaying by my mistaken and I have just removed unnecessary parts as requested, but I posted the screenshots to illustrate how the same code in different places did not gave me the same result, discarding the possibilitiy that I might have put something wrong. Do you not think this is useful for anyone who intends to help me?

Comment: Your code gives the same result at using `book` document class as well at `beamer` (as expected). In both cases label of angle is bad positioned.

Comment: @Zarko but the complex number $z$ is placed where I wanted to be in `book` document that is right the point $(3,2)$ while it is placed behind the angle and next to the origin in `beamer`. Any suggestion?

Comment: This is all a bit complex now since `tkz-euclide` has been upgraded. So the output differs from version to version. Moreover,  with the newest version you are no longer supposed to add `\usetkzobj{all}` and you do not need `\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}`. However, if I am not mistaken, the line `\tkzLabelPoints[right](z)` does not work because you did not define `z`. So I suggest that you update your TeX installation and then see what you get.

Comment: How to upgrade if I am using overleaf?

Comment: $z$ is the way I would like to display for my $A(3,2)$ point.. It is ok for book, but not of beamer

Comment: This is a very simple diagram. Maybe it is the best to draw it with plain TikZ , given that you cannot update your installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, i.e. as long as overleaf does not update the packages you are using, you may resort to just plain Ti*k*Z. This is a very simple diagram, for which the plain Ti*k*Z code is even shorter than its `tkz-euclide` counterpart (at least for the versions present here).

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some pic}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,dot/.style={circle,fill=gray,draw,inner sep=1.2pt}]
 \path (3,2) node[dot,label=above
 right:{$z=x+\mathsf{i}\,y=|z|\,\mathsf{e}^{\mathsf{i}\theta}$}] (z){};
 \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0) node[dot] (O){} -- (0:1) arc[start angle=0,end
  angle={atan2(2,3)},radius=1] node[midway,right]{$\theta$};
 \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0);
 \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,2.5);
 \draw[-latex,semithick] (O) -- (z) node[midway,above,sloped]{$|z|$};
 \draw[dashed] (z|-O) node[dot,label=below:$x$]{} edge[<-] (z) 
  (z-|O) node[dot,label=left:$y$]{} edge[<-] (z) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using Overleaf the following MWE works fine in the `book` and in the `beamer` document classes. In both cases the resulted images are the same.

MWE for book:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5, xmax=4, ymin=-.5, ymax=2.5]
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}]
\tkzDefPoints{3/2/A,3/0/B,0/0/C}
%
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=gray!30,size=1](B,C,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.25](B,C,A){$\theta$}
%
\tkzDrawSegments(C,A)
\tkzLabelSegment[above,sloped](C,A){$|z|$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$z$}
%
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzPointShowCoord[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$](A)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

MWE for beamer:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test \texttt{tkz-euclide} image}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5, xmax=4, ymin=-.5, ymax=2.5]
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,label={}]
\tkzDefPoints{3/2/A,3/0/B,0/0/C}
%
\tkzMarkAngle[fill=gray!30,size=1](B,C,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.25](B,C,A){$\theta$}
%
\tkzDrawSegments(C,A)
\tkzLabelSegment[above,sloped](C,A){$|z|$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$z$}
%
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzPointShowCoord[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$](A)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, in both cases the code for image as well quality resulted images are the same. In comparison to your MWE, it is a bit reorganized. Also is defined position of the label `$z$`.